# SQL Stored Procedure Insert All Dates From Current Month Not In

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables

- Table `Person` with a column `PersonID` (`integer`)
- Table `CarePlanReport` with columns `PersonID` (`integer`), Shift (`nvarchar(5)` - will hold the text values ‘day’ or ‘night’), `CarePlanDate` (`datetime`), `Details` (`nvarchar(50)`)

I need a stored procedure that will for all dates in the current month, insert 2 records into the `CarePlanReport` table for each `Person.PersonID` (a day shift and a night shift) if they don't already exist. This is because each person requires both a day and night shift record for each day in the current month. The problem is a new person could be added during any day in the current month and the missing records will need to be added - so this procedure will need to be run multiple times in any given month. Existing records will remain unchanged because they could already store important details.

EXAMPLE

`Person` table holds:

```
PersonId
--------
   1
   2
```

`CarePlanReport` holds for current month

```
PersonID   Shirt    CarePlanDate
----------------------------------
   1       day      2015/03/01
   2       day      2015/03/01
   1       night    2015/03/01
   2       night    2015/03/01
   .. and so on for each day in the month ....
   1       day      2015/03/31
   2       day      2015/03/31
   1       night    2015/03/31
   2       night    2015/03/31
```

I used this to return all dates for the current month (not sure if it’s the most efficient method)

```
declare @date datetime
set @date =  cast(YEAR(GETDATE()) as nvarchar(4)) +  RIGHT('00' +     cast(Month(GETDATE()) as nvarchar(2)), 2) + '01';

with d as (
    select @date as Date
    union all
    select dateadd(dd,1,Date)
    from d
    where month(date) = month(@Date)
)
select d.date 
from d 
where month(date) = month(@Date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tfa

It would be good if you write a trigger and that should get invoked as a new record inserted in the Person Table. Let me know if any need any help for this. You have to have few set of validations in your trigger
Use the below procedure  which will insert "day" and "night" record for each personid. Just you have to invoke once in a month.

```
create procedure [dbo].[InsertsRecords]
as
begin
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
declare @NoOfDays int
declare @lv_count int =1
declare @LastDateOfMonth date 
declare @getdates date
declare @lv_personid  int
declare @FirstDateOfMonth date
SET @DATE=convert(date,getdate())
set @LastDateOfMonth =(select DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@date)+1,0)))
set @FirstDateOfMonth=(SELECT convert(date,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
declare rcds_cur cursor  for
select personid from dbo.person where personid not in (select personid from dbo.CarePlanReport between 
@FirstDateOfMonth and @LastDateOfMonth )

open rcds_cur
FETCH NEXT FROM rcds_cur into @lv_personid
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
set @NoOfDays=( Select Day(EOMONTH(@DATE)) AS [Current Month])
set @NoOfDays=@NoOfDays-1
     while (@lv_count<=@NoOfDays)
     begin   
     set @getdates=(select DATEADD(dd,-@lv_count , @LastDateOfMonth))
     insert into dbo.CarePlanReport values (@lv_personid,'day',@getdates,'day shift')
     insert into dbo.CarePlanReport values (@lv_personid,'night',@getdates,'night shift')
     set @lv_count=@lv_count+1

     end
FETCH NEXT FROM rcds_cur into @lv_personid
end
close rcds_cur
deallocate rcds_cur
end
```

Comment: Not sure how a trigger would work because the person table would remain mostly unchanged. And as each new month rolls a button is pressed that would execute the stored procedure to create the records for the new month.

Comment: Works perfect as a trigger thanks for your help much appreciated